# Add a viariable to an each object in an array

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a solution to add a variable to an object in a array.

My array of objects:

```
[
{
    "BasketDetail_ID": "91",
    "Pos": "1",
    "BasketBasket_ID": "17",
},
{
    "BasketDetail_ID": "92",
    "Pos": "2",
    "BasketBasket_ID": "17",
},
{
    "BasketDetail_ID": "93",
    "Pos": "3",
    "BasketBasket_ID": "17",
},
{
    "BasketDetail_ID": "94",
    "Pos": "4",
    "BasketBasket_ID": "17",
},
{
    "BasketDetail_ID": "95",
    "Pos": "5",
    "BasketBasket_ID": "17",
},
{
    "BasketDetail_ID": "96",
    "Pos": "6",
    "BasketBasket_ID": "17",
},
{
    "BasketDetail_ID": "97",
    "Pos": "7",
    "BasketBasket_ID": "17",
},
{
    "BasketDetail_ID": "98",
    "Pos": "8",
    "BasketBasket_ID": "17",

}
]
```

My objects do not have names.

I tried to make a push for each object:

```
var length = basketDetails.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        $scope.basketDetails[i].push({'detailTotalPrice': $scope.detailTotalPrice});
    }
```

Here I always get an error:
$scope.basketDetails[i].push is not a function

the updated array should look like:

```
[
{
    "BasketDetail_ID": "91",
    "Pos": "1",
    "BasketBasket_ID": "17",
    "detailTotalPrice": "100",
},
{
    "BasketDetail_ID": "92",
    "Pos": "2",
    "BasketBasket_ID": "17",
    "detailTotalPrice": "100",
},
{
    "BasketDetail_ID": "93",
    "Pos": "3",
    "BasketBasket_ID": "17",
    "detailTotalPrice": "100",
},
{
    "BasketDetail_ID": "94",
    "Pos": "4",
    "BasketBasket_ID": "17",
    "detailTotalPrice": "100",
},
{
    "BasketDetail_ID": "95",
    "Pos": "5",
    "BasketBasket_ID": "17",
    "detailTotalPrice": "100",
},
{
    "BasketDetail_ID": "96",
    "Pos": "6",
    "BasketBasket_ID": "17",
    "detailTotalPrice": "100",
},
{
    "BasketDetail_ID": "97",
    "Pos": "7",
    "BasketBasket_ID": "17",
    "detailTotalPrice": "100",
},
{
    "BasketDetail_ID": "98",
    "Pos": "8",
    "BasketBasket_ID": "17",
    "detailTotalPrice": "100",

}
]
```

have somebody an idea to fix this problem?

Comment: `$scope.basketDetails[i]['detailTotalPrice'] = $scope.detailTotalPrice`

Comment: `$scope.basketDetails[i].detailTotalPrice= $scope.detailTotalPrice;`

Comment: Code you shared does not contain `$scope.basketDetails[i].add `

Comment: thank's it works finde :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript arrays have a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method.

This allows you to do stuff like:

```
basketDetails.forEach(x => x.detailTotalPrice = "100");
```

Or if you are still using ES5:

```
basketDetails.forEach(function(x) {x.detailsTotalprice = "100"});
```

Here is a working example you can click Run on to see in action:

```js
let basketDetails = [
{
    "BasketDetail_ID": "91",
    "Pos": "1",
    "BasketBasket_ID": "17",
},
{
    "BasketDetail_ID": "92",
    "Pos": "2",
    "BasketBasket_ID": "17",
},
{
    "BasketDetail_ID": "93",
    "Pos": "3",
    "BasketBasket_ID": "17",
},
{
    "BasketDetail_ID": "94",
    "Pos": "4",
    "BasketBasket_ID": "17",
},
{
    "BasketDetail_ID": "95",
    "Pos": "5",
    "BasketBasket_ID": "17",
},
{
    "BasketDetail_ID": "96",
    "Pos": "6",
    "BasketBasket_ID": "17",
},
{
    "BasketDetail_ID": "97",
    "Pos": "7",
    "BasketBasket_ID": "17",
},
{
    "BasketDetail_ID": "98",
    "Pos": "8",
    "BasketBasket_ID": "17",

}
]

basketDetails.forEach(x => x.detailTotalPrice = "100");

console.log(JSON.stringify(basketDetails));
```

It should be noted, this is not a JSON array. It is a JavaScript array. JSON is a notation to serialize Objects, Arrays and values into strings. The question you are asking actually has nothing to do with JSON.

Finally the method `push` you are trying to use is a an array function, but you are trying to use it on a Plain Old JavaScript Object, which does not have a method `push`.